# Why does easy_install extract some python eggs and not others?

Tags: python, egg

Looking in my /usr/local/lib/python.../dist-package directory, I have `.egg` directories and `.egg` files.

Why does the installer choose to extra packages to the `.egg` directory, yet leave other files with `.egg` extensions?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60166477/1959808

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33014444/1959808

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7287318/1959808

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If the package contains only pure-Python code, it can stay as just an egg file.  The Python interpreter can load the Python modules directly from the egg.  If the package contains modules written in C or other data, then egg needs to be extracted so the C modules and/or data can be accessed.  That's the default behavior of packages, I believe.  Newer versions of Python might be able to load C modules from egg files; I'm not sure about that part.

The creator of the package can also specifically instruct the installer to unzip the package, by passing [`zip_safe = False`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/miscellaneous.html#setting-the-zip-safe-flag) to `setup()` in their `setup.py`.

Finally, the person doing the installing can tell `easy_install` explicitly to unpack eggs by passing it the [`-Z` option](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deprecated/easy_install.html#command-line-options) or by setting `zip_ok = False` in the `pydistutils.cfg`.

Answer (score 5):

I can't explain why some eggs are zipped (the files) and some are directories, but I can offer this: if you hate zipped eggs (like I do) put this in the `[easy_install]` section of your `~/.pydistutils.cfg`:

```
zip_ok = false
```