# Is zip_safe only relevant for the egg format?

Tags: python, setuptools, egg

If I read [this](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/wheel-vs-egg/) correctly, then the egg format is something one should not use anymore. Instead, one should use the wheels format. [Others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2051195/562769) seem to read this the same way.

With this assumption: Is `zip_safe` relevant for any other distribution format than egg?

### What I found

According to [this](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files):

> A boolean (True or False) flag specifying whether the project can be safely installed and run from a zip file. If this argument is not supplied, the bdist_egg command will have to analyze all of your project’s contents for possible problems each time it builds an egg.

Setuptools does not mention wheels. So I guess it is not relevant for wheels. So if I don't build eggs, I don't need this?

But then, if I install packages with `pip install -e .`, it seems as if it creates an egg file (well, an `[package name].egg-info` )... so maybe egg isn't outdated, even with Python 3.8?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [section "Is it possible to import Python code directly from a wheel file?" from *PEP 427*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#is-it-possible-to-import-python-code-directly-from-a-wheel-file) could answer your question. In short, it is technically possible to leave the packages zipped, but there are advantages in installing them unzipped: easier access to metadata and prevention against some corner cases (can't execute binaries in a zip file). So that would explain why the `zip_safe` is not relevant anymore in general and for *wheels* in particular.

Nowadays, I believe *eggs* are only used in some rare specific cases. One of them is the *setuptools develop mode* or *pip editable mode*, in order to take advantage of the [*egg link*](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formats.html#egg-links) feature.

Answer (score 0):

CPython repository [doesn't mention `zip_safe`](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?q=zip_safe&type=Code) at all; i.e. `distutils` doesn't support it.

It can be found in [`setuptools` code](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/search?q=zip_safe&type=Code) but really used only in [`bdist_egg`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/e3068ee28f37064d08c3f55557536454be47b0cd/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py#L220).

So yes, the option is relevant only for eggs.